# How to detect if a specific button has been clicked?

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

I have various colour buttons that change the colour of a movieclip on click but I want to write code that says like `if btnRed has been clicked, apply red ColorTransform`. This is because I have multiple buttons and I don't want to have to write methods that are almost identical just with different RGB multiplier values. Is there a way of doing it so that the event listener for each button calls the same method but then within that method it basically says `if redBtn is clicked, change color to red`, `if blueBtn is clicked, change color to blue` etc.

Answer (score 2):

As M4tchB0X3r indicated, use a `Dictionary` to store a lookup of button object to color transform. Here is working code, assuming your button names are `btnRed`, `btnGreen`, and `btnBlue`, and that you have some kind of named object on the stage called `box1`.

They key points here are that the `Dictionary` can use object references as keys (not just integers and strings as with the simple `Object` type), and that the `target` property of an `Event` object holds a reference to the thing that raised the event--in this case a button. In fact it's probably safer to use `currentTarget`, because sometimes `target` is a parent or child display object, due to the way events can bubble up and down the tree.

```
import flash.utils.Dictionary;
import flash.geom.ColorTransform;  

var buttonToTransform:Dictionary = new Dictionary();
buttonToTransform[btnRed]   = new ColorTransform(1.0, 0.2, 0.2);
buttonToTransform[btnGreen] = new ColorTransform(0.2, 1.0, 0.2);
buttonToTransform[btnBlue]  = new ColorTransform(0.2, 0.2, 1.0);

// Note: for..in iterates over the keys of an object
// (vs. for each, which iterates over the values)
for(var btn:* in buttonToTransform) { 
    btn.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, onTransform);
}

function onTransform(e:MouseEvent):void { 
    this.box1.transform.colorTransform = buttonToTransform[e.currentTarget];
}
```

Comment: beat me to it ;) , just wrote up basically the same thing.

Answer (score 0):

Hold all your Buttons in an Array, in the `CLICK` Event determin which one was pressed with `buttonArray.indexOf(event.target);`
then get the according color value from a `map` like a `Dictionary` or an `Object`.

You could also keep your Buttons in the Dictionary itself and loop through it to find your color.

Comment: Are there any working examples or code snippets for this that might prove useful? All of my buttons are named like `redBtn`, `blueBtn`, `greenBtn` etc.